# heuristic for expected number of visits random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

What is the heuristic argument that explains why, on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, $d \geq 3$, the expected number of visits of a random walk starting from the origin at $x$ is of order
$$
O(|x|^{2-d})?
$$

Comment: Expected number of times to visit the origin is a finite constant (depending on $d$). Probability of reaching $x$ at all is on the order of $|x|^{2-d}$. Multiply the two together.

Comment: Here is another heuristic. Let number of visits to a point $r$ away if $f(r)$. Noting that $R_n$ is $\Theta_p(\sqrt n)$, we get $\int_0^{\Theta(\sqrt n)} f(r)Cr^{d-1}=n$ which yields $f(n)=\Theta (r^{2-d})$.

Comment: Concerning the first comment, I see that, but then the question would be, what is the heuristic of the order of probability of reaching $x$ at all.

Concerning the second comment, what do you mean by "noting that $R_n$ is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$? I don't see how they are defined.

Comment: $R_n=||S_n||_2$ and is $\Theta_p(\sqrt n)$ - basically saying that distance from the origin is order of $n^{1/2}$ so you need to only integrate up to $r=C\sqrt n$ as sites beyond won't be visited by time $n$.

Comment: Here is another, possibly the simplest, explanation. Probability of being at the origin at time $n$ is $O(n^{-d/2})$, hence expected number of visits to the origin after time $n$ is $O(n^{\frac{2-d}2})$. It takes time $n=\Omega(|x|^2)$ to reach a point $|x|$ away, hence expected number of visits to this point is $O(|x|^{2-d})$.